# Exiftool.exe in QGIS

Tags: python

I am developing a GIS application and in my code I need to call the [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) executable which is installed in a different path.
I call in command prompt and in OSGEO4W shell and both are fine.
But when I write in my code doesn't give any error but doesn't work.

```
import os
import subprocess
os.chdir('C:/micmac/binaire-aux')
comand3 = 'exiftool.exe (...) args (...)'
subprocess.call(comand3)
```

In the command lines I use this code:

```
C:/micmac/binaire-aux/exiftool (...) args (...)
```

The args are exactly the same.

When I try just:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/micmac/binaire-aux')
comand3 = 'exiftool.exe'
subprocess.call(comand3)
```

This works fine. I don't understand why doesn't work with the arguments, if they are the same.

Comment: +1 I spent a whole week one day dealing with tif files whose location in their exif headers differed from the location in their .tfw files.

Comment: Maybe a pyexiv2 would be easier to use. http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/

Comment: Assuming that this is [the tool you are asking about](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) can you explain why you think your question is GIS specific rather than general development ([so]).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am developing a GIS application that's why I added the question here. I edit the question. I will think off pyexiv2 however I did not want to install too much external packages. If I run in the command line inside the folder with the images it is everything ok. How do I run a command (with subprocess) inside a specific path?